# logout from google plus with gwt

Tags: email, gwt, logout, google-plus

I am developing an aplication with gwt for login and logout from google plus but I don't found info,I also tried to return the mail when you connect but I get null.

This is the code I use:

```
public void getMe(final Plus plus) {
    plus.people().get("me").to(new Receiver<Person>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Person person) {
            dataSvc = GWT.create(LoginService.class);
            name = person.getDisplayName();
            mail = person.getEmails().get(0).getValue();
            dataSvc.changeData("2", name, callback);
        }
    }).fire();    
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to do and what platform you are using? Specifically, can you explain more about where LoginService.class comes from? It does not look like a call to the Google+ REST API.